# Power BI Web - How to add an Image to Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

How do I add an image to a Power BI **Report**?  I know how to add an image to a dashboard

This refers to Power BI within a browser, not Power BI desktop

I cannot use Power BI desktop as that does not support Stream Analytics data

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are stuck editing in a browser, then there is no way to add an image.

There are visuals (e.g. table) that can show an image based on a URL, but the URL must already exist in the dataset. You cant edit or create columns or measures using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any native way to do this, however,There is a workaround which is:-

1.Add any chart type

2.Apply any empty dataset to it

3.Under format scroll down the Plot Area

4.Add Image

Answer (score 0):

**Add images, videos, and more to your dashboard**

By adding a tile to your dashboard, you can place an image, text box, video, streaming data, or web code on the dashboard.

[Watch Amanda add tiles to a dashboard.](https://youtu.be/e2PD8m1Q0vU)

You can add an image, text box, video, streaming data, or web code directly to your dashboard.

Select the arrow next to Edit on the top menu, and then select Add a tile.

Select which type of tile to add:

- Web content
- Image
- Text box
- Video
- Custom streaming data

**Add an image**

If you want to add your company logo or some other image to your dashboard, you save the image file online and link to it. Make sure security credentials aren't required to access the image file. For example, because OneDrive and SharePoint require authentication, images stored there can't be added to a dashboard this way. Also, images can't be in .svg format.

From the Add tile window, select Image > Next.

From the Add image tile window, add the image information:

a. To display a title above the image, select Display title and subtitle and enter a Title and an optional Subtitle.

b. Enter the image URL.

c. To make the tile a hyperlink, select the Set custom link and enter the URL.

When colleagues click the image or title, they'll be taken to this URL.

d. Select Apply.

On the dashboard, resize and move the image as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround:

(in Edit mode, of course)

1. insert a blank button (Buttons->Blank),
2. in the Format Pane under the "Style" section, for the "icon type" set custom
3. click on "browse" to choose your image file

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to do so in the desktop version. This will be easiest way to insert it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Upload Image to a Web Location:

Store the image you want to add to your report in a publicly accessible web location. This could be a cloud storage service like OneDrive or Azure Blob Storage.
Get the Image URL:

Obtain the direct URL of the image file.
Add Web Content to Report:

In your Power BI report, use the "Web Content" option to add the image.
Go to the "Home" tab.
Select "Web" from the "External data" section.
Enter the URL of the image.
Adjust Image Size and Position:

Once you've added the image using web content, you may need to adjust its size and position using the formatting options.